# Given Pressure Altitude and CAS, calculate Mach Number using Jeppesen E6B

Tags: e6b

Just wondering how to calculate Mach Number from CAS and PA on an E6B. For example: given FL290, CAS 280kts, Find the Mach number.

I used to use the round CR3 but I recently switched to the old-school Jeppesen E6B and found out there are far fewer functions on the front side.

Comment: @MaxPower On the CR3 there is a window that has CAS over PA which gives you a Mach number directly and you can use the Mach number and temperature to find TAS. The original question is based on a 727 that has a yaw damper failure continues to its destination and finds the TOD. Since a 727 flies faster than 200kts so compressibility became an issue thus converting directly to Mach can bypass that issue. I got 456kts TAS on the E6B where the correct answer should be around 436kts TAS

Answer (score 2):

1. Not sure about the structure of your question.  The Mach-to-KTAS ratio is solely a function of OAT (outside air temperature) and is *not* a function of pressure altitude.  The speed of sound is the same at *any* pressure or altitude for a given OAT.  *Remember that at higher speeds compressibility will make your Indicated (IAT) read higher than the actual OAT, and you may have to convert IAT to OAT).*
2. First you have to physically “find” the `Mach No Index` pointer.  This is an arrow that appears in the *right-side* window of the wheel, the same one we use to set pressure altitude under the OAT when doing TAS calculations.  This window makes sense, because Mach Number is an OAT:TAS ratio just as pressure altitude is.  Turn the wheel so that the big `Speed Index Arrow` (`60` on the wheel) is pointed to around `39` on the outer wheel.  You should now see `Mach No Index` in the Pressure Altitude window.
3. Place the observed OAT over the `Mach No Index`.
4. The wheel is now aligned in such a way that the outer "fixed" ring on the computer board represents KTAS and the outer-most ring of the rotating wheel represents Mach number.  We can verify we're in "the right part of town" by looking at the `10` pointer on the wheel, which represents Mach 1.0.  We know that Mach 1 will usually be in the range of 550 to 600 Kts in really cold air, to about 700 knots in really warm air.  So the `10` on the wheel ought to be between about 55 and 70.  For our examples, let say the OAT is -20c and we have set the `Mach No Index` under `-20c`.  We can see that the speed of sound (over the `10` on the wheel) is 620 Kts.
5. **Mach to KTAS**  If you know your Mach number is 0.75, then find `75` on the *wheel* and KTAS will be the number *above* it in the ring of the fixed board. You should get about `465` KTAS.
6. **KTAS to Mach**  If your KTAS is 510Kts, then find `51` on the outer ring and read Mach Number directly below it on the wheel.  You should see Mach `0.82` on the wheel.

That's it.  OAT goes over the Mach No Index in the window, and then ring is set so that Kts is over the corresponding Mach.

Comment: Because I'm feeling pedantic: Mach:TAS does change independent of OAT at extreme altitudes. Mainly because of both compositional changes in the gas mix, and non-ideal gas interactions, clouds will also have a small effect. This has no practical effect on aircraft navigation accuracy, just the uncertainty of winds aloft is orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: Yes, that’s a great point.  I mentioned compressibility in my answer, and that does have to be taken into consideration at TASes above about 200kts or so.  But you are right to point out that the ISA atmosphere is based on linear temperature and pressure lapse rates to 36,000 feet.  Above about FL360, a really accurate calculation is going to get a bit more complicated.

Comment: I was talking about the average molecular weight of the gas; and attraction/repulsion forces between the particles that are neglected in most practical formulas involving low Earth atmosphere(tropo and statosphere).